# Querying and extracting a Unicode value from sqlite3 in Python

Tags: python, unicode, sqlite, indic

I'm having issues trying to extract utf-8 encoded values stored in an sqlite3 database in python.

```
>> import sqlite3
>> connection=sqlite3.connect('mySQLite3DB.db')
>> cursor=connection.cursor()
>> word = unichr(2675)+unichr(37) # ੳ%
>> cursor.execute('select distinct col1 from table1 where col1 like ? limit 3', word)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ProgrammingError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/punjcoder/code/<ipython-input-10-358f7ffe8df0> in <module>()
----> 1 cursor.execute('select distinct col1 from table1 where col1 like ? limit 3', word)

ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 2 supplied.
```

Now if I run the query by manually inserting the unicode, it runs. However I'm not able to retrieve the text, but buffer ptr instead.

```
>> cursor.execute('select distinct col1 from table1 where col1 like "ੳ%" limit 3')
<sqlite3.Cursor at 0x10dab8500>
>> for row in cursor.fetchall():
>>      print row
(<read-write buffer ptr 0x10dabf898, size 3 at 0x10dabf858>,)
```

I have alread seen the links below, however can't seem to find a way to make it work. I'm working on Python 2.7.2 and SQLite 3.7.10. Your help is appreciated in advance.

- [Extracting values from SQLite database in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162701/extracting-values-from-sqlite-database-in-python)
- [SQLite, python, unicode, and non-utf data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392732/sqlite-python-unicode-and-non-utf-data)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
 cursor.execute('select distinct col1 from table1 where col1 like ? limit 3', [word])
```

I expect that you're treating the unicode string `word` as an iterable and seeing each character separately.

Comment: That helped for the Incorrect number of bindings. For the second adding this at the top of the script helped.

    import sys
    reload(sys) 
    sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")

Comment: @PunjCoder, don't use that "trick".  The default encoding of `ascii` is expected by some standard libraries.  Just explicitly `.decode('utf8')` instead.